# Why is the trace not happening in my MouseEvent.CLICK handler?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, counter, mouselistener

Okay so I'm making a really simple game where you have to click and move the mouse back and forth across a certain area to gain points. 
I have a `hit` `MovieClip`, but it won't trace hovers or even clicks when I certainly am clicking there. Is it the code or is it my fault?

If you could provide any insight into how to properly have a counter that increases when you have a `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` and are repeatedly moving the mouse over the test area that would be so good.

```
var counter:int = 0
hit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseOverHandler);
function fl_MouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
counter++;
trace("Moused over");   
}
```

Comment: There isn't much to go on, please tell us more about your `hit` `MovieClip` and how you have created it. Maybe you just need to set its `mouseChildren` property to false? As a side note, you give `hit` and MouseEvent for `CLICK` but your functions seems to be for `MouseOver`.

Comment: oh it was originally for MouseOver but i changed it to click because that made it easier to see for sure what wasn't working. 
Hit movieclip is simply a blue square with an alpha set to 0

Comment: How did you create it? through code? through the Flash Authoring tool (flash cs5 or other versions)?

Comment: uhh i used the rectangle tool haha, and converted it to a symbol, the above code is the only code i have running

Comment: Have you tried giving this rectangle an alpha value that isn't 0?

Comment: yeah, i tried that too. and the rectangle is on the top layer as well.

Comment: your rectangle tool produces a `Shape` which cannot listen to clicks. Convert that symbol's base type to `MovieClip`.

Comment: did you convert the rectangle to movieclip?